# No records are fetching while querying to postgres Db using Apache spark sql

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

This is how i am making the query. The records are available in DB.

```
sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbUrl")).
        option("user", configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbUser")).
        option("password", configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbPassword")).
        option("ssl", configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbSsl")).
        option("sslmode", "verify-full").
        option("searchpath", configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbSchema")).
        option("sslrootcert", configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbSslRootCert")).
        option("sslcert", configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbSslCertPath")).
        option("sslkey", configuredProperties.getProperty("ProgramDbSslKey")).option("query", "select activity_type, description from "+tableName).load();
```

i am trying to display the result by using below code.

```
Dataset<Row> free_item_rows = freeItemRepository.CustomQuery("Program_activity_log");
free_item_rows.show();
```